# Adding ActionListener in for cycle throws StackOverflowError

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, stack-overflow

I am getting `java.lang.StackOverflowError` when I run this code:

```
Map<JButton, Integer> buttons = new HashMap<JButton, Integer>();
JPanel main = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 4, 4));

    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        JButton jb = new JButton(i+"");
        jb.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
        switch(i) {
        case 0:
            jb.setText("1");
        case 1:
            jb.setText("2");
        case 2:
            jb.setText("3");
        (...) 
        case 15:
            jb.setText("/");
        }
        buttons.put(jb, i);
        main.add(jb);
    }

    this.getContentPane().add(main);
```

Why is that error happening? And how could I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Probably you get a infinite loop while adding the action listener, are you sure your `MyActionListener` code is right? can you post the full stack trace and also the full code?

Comment: Also it will always set the text to "/". You forgot to add `break;` to your cases.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. The problem was with using external `MyActionListener` class. I had to create `void actionPerformed()` in class where I create new JButtons and also add there `implements ActionListener`.

Anyway thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
    case 1:
        jb.setText("2");
     **break**
```

Try to put break after the switch cases. I suggest you to also use  "default" at the end of switch cases.

Solution 2:
Please check if you have any infinite recursive functions like

```
public void foo(){
  foo();  //never stops
}
```

For more information about stackoverflow error 
[What is a StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error)

Comment: I highly doubt this answer. Your reputation is `not found`! :)